# Returning full duplicate rows using Laravel's query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, inner-join, query-builder

I am looking to return the full information on duplicate records from my table.

I am currently using the following:

```
DB::table($entity['table'])
                ->select('*')
                ->groupBy($entity['columns'])
                ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
                ->get();
```

Which is great, it returns the duplicate records, however, this only returns one of the records I need to return all the duplicates so that I can greet the user with a choice on which one to delete or keep.

How can I modify the above query to accomplish that?

Comment: what is the content of `$['columns']`? Is this a string or an array?

Comment: its an array at the moment, but just one element, just trying to get it to work how I need at the moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining against the same table will allow you to retrieve the duplicate records without just getting a single version of it (caused by your groupBy in your question)

```
$entity['columns'] = ['username', 'surname'];

$groupBy = implode(',', $entity['columns']);

$subQuery = DB::table('list')
    ->select('*')
    ->groupBy($groupBy)
    ->havingRaw('(count(id) > 1))');

$result = DB::table('list')
    ->select('*')
    ->join(
        DB::raw("({$subQuery->toSql()}) dup"), function($join) use ($entity) {
            foreach ($entity['columns'] as $column) {
                $join->on('list.'.$column, '=', 'dup.'.$column);
            }
        })
    ->toSql();
    // or ->get(); obviously

    dd($result);
```

Comment: This seems to return multiple duplicates from the query

Comment: Do you have a sample dataset?

Comment: Sure, checkout this question as I ended up posting it separately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104074/select-duplicates-query-returns-duplicates-mysql

Comment: Generates the error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Remove extra bracket from $subQuery that solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to join back to the table in $entity['table'] on the columns in the $entity['columns'] to get the duplicates.

Also, the select('*') is not really a good idea even if you are using mysql. This is against the sql standard and works in mysql only if it is configured in a certain way. If the configuration changes or you migrate your app to a mysql server with different configuration on sql modes, your query will fail.

I would use $entity['columns'] in the select list as well.

In sql the query should look like as follows:

```
select table.* from table inner join
  (select field1, field2 from table t
  group by field1, field2
  having count(*)>1) t1
on table.field1=t1.field1 and table.field2=t1.field2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, This will work and I can see what is going on here but my question was aimed at more how do I do this within the Laravel query builder? Any ideas?

Comment: There are lots of topics on how to build subqueries in Laravel, see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319240/laravel-how-to-use-derived-tables-subqueries-in-the-laravel-query-builder

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using whereIn and a function to query the same table that you are working with.

Let say you have a scenario where you want to look for duplicate records containing the same last name in the user table.

**Database Table** - User

```
      --- user_id --- first_name --- last_name --- email ---

            1           Dan           Smith     dan@test.com
            2           Jim           Jones     jim@test.com
            3           Amy           Grant     amy@test.com
            4           Bob           Brown     bob@test.com
            5           Sue           Davis     sue@test.com
            6           Leo           Grant     leo@test.com
            7           Ann           Grant     ann@test.com
```

Then you can use the following code;

```
 $duplicates = DB::table('user')
 ->select('user_id', 'last_name')
 ->whereIn('user_id', function ($q){
             $q->select('user_id')
             ->from('user')
             ->groupBy('last_name')
             ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1');
 })->get();
```

Which will return the following;

```
      --- user_id --- last_name

            3           Grant
            6           Grant
            7           Grant
```