# Select duplicates query returns duplicates MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, inner-join

I have the following query that I want to return all the duplicated rows to the user for them to decide which one to use:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY barcode HAVING (COUNT(id) > 1)) dup 
ON `table`.`column` = `dup`.`column`
```

Each part of this query appears to return the correct response but when adding the 2 together I am getting duplicates of the duplicates if that makes sense. Any ideas on what is going on?

**My table data**

```
+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id |        barcode         |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  2 | 0000000002800000008741 | 2015-10-05 12:04:52 | 2015-10-05 12:04:52 |
|  3 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 13:15:02 | 2015-10-05 13:37:51 |
|  4 | 0000000002800000008741 | 2015-10-05 13:22:38 | 2015-10-05 13:22:38 |
|  5 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 13:22:38 | 2015-10-05 13:22:38 |
|  6 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 13:23:29 | 2015-10-05 13:23:29 |
|  7 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 13:24:49 | 2015-10-05 13:24:49 |
|  8 | 0000000002800000008741 | 2015-10-05 13:24:49 | 2015-10-05 13:24:49 |
|  9 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 13:37:51 | 2015-10-05 13:37:51 |
| 10 | 0000000002800000008741 | 2015-10-05 13:37:51 | 2015-10-05 13:37:51 |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**The output of the above query**

```
+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id |        barcode         |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  2 | 0000000002800000008741 | 2015-10-05 12:04:52 | 2015-10-05 12:04:52 |
|  3 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 13:15:02 | 2015-10-05 13:37:51 |
|  4 | 0000000002800000008741 | 2015-10-05 13:22:38 | 2015-10-05 13:22:38 |
|  5 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 13:22:38 | 2015-10-05 13:22:38 |
|  6 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 13:23:29 | 2015-10-05 13:23:29 |
|  7 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 13:24:49 | 2015-10-05 13:24:49 |
|  8 | 0000000002800000008741 | 2015-10-05 13:24:49 | 2015-10-05 13:24:49 |
|  9 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 13:37:51 | 2015-10-05 13:37:51 |
| 10 | 0000000002800000008741 | 2015-10-05 13:37:51 | 2015-10-05 13:37:51 |
| 11 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 13:39:05 | 2015-10-05 13:39:05 |
| 12 | 0000000002800000008741 | 2015-10-05 16:16:41 | 2015-10-05 16:16:41 |
| 13 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-05 16:39:56 | 2015-10-05 16:39:56 |
| 14 | 0000000002800000008738 | 2015-10-06 10:12:32 | 2015-10-06 10:12:52 |
| 15 | 0000000002800000008741 | 2015-10-06 10:17:30 | 2015-10-06 10:17:30 |
| 16 | 0000000002800000008741 | 2015-10-05 16:50:40 | 2015-10-05 16:50:40 |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem without seeing an example result set (would be helpful to add one to the question)- but I get the feeling you might just need the `DISTINCT` keyword: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM...`

Comment: This logic produces the desired result set. Only difference is that inner query only selects 'table.column'  `SELECT * from table INNER JOIN ( Select table.column from table group by table.column having(count(id)>1)) dup
ON table.column = dup.column;`

Comment: This gives me the exact same result.

Comment: I'll try with your data

Comment: `SELECT * FROM test_table 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT barcode FROM test_table GROUP BY barcode HAVING (count(id) > 1)) dup
ON test_table.barcode = dup.barcode; `   This query returns exactly 10 rows in my test environment. It's very interesting you get a different result.

Comment: @kunoichi the sample data has 9 rows. Did you mean 9? I get 9 rows when I run the above query. Similarly when adding rows in which aren't duplicates they're excluded from the result set, as expected.

Comment: @SeriousJelly your query column names don't match up with the sample table columns. Can you put the exact query and table structure you're using into your question?

Comment: @Ben Swinburne It seems I added an extra row to the data set. That's why I get 10 rows instead of 9.