# Object of class Closure could not be converted to string laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am going through multiple iterations of this query, I assume that I am missing something somewhere in my query that is causing me to get an error as follows:

> Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

My query:

```
$test = UnitStandard::select(DB::raw("
                    count(t1.code),
                    t1.code,
                    t1.id,
                    t1.provider_id,
                    t1.name,
                    t1.nqf_level,
                    t1.credits,
                    t1.type,
                    MAX(t1.shared_id),
                    setas.name as setaName,
                    providers.name as providerName
"))
->from(function ($query){

        $query->select(DB::raw("*"))
            ->from("unit_standards")
            ->where("provider_id", "=", 1)
            ->whereNull("shared_id")
            ->orWhere("shared_id", "=", 2)
            ->orderBy("unit_standards.code", "asc");
})
->join('setas', 't1.seta_id', '=', 'setas.id')
->join('providers', 't1.provider_id', '=', 'providers.id')
->where('shared_id', '=', 2)
->orWhere('t1.provider_id', '=', 1)
->groupBy('code')
->havingRaw('COUNT(code) >= 1')
->orderBy('code', 'asc')
->paginate(50);
```

### Update

See full error snippet below

[image]

### Update

Raw working MySQL:

```
 SELECT 
count(t1.code), 
t1.code, 
t1.id,
t1.provider_id, 
t1.name,
t1.nqf_level,
t1.credits,
t1.type,
MAX(t1.shared_id),
setas.name as setaName,
providers.name as providerName
FROM(
SELECT * FROM unit_standards WHERE (provider_id = 1 AND shared_id IS NULL) OR shared_id = 2 ORDER BY `unit_standards`.`code` ASC
) AS t1
JOIN setas on t1.seta_id = setas.id
JOIN providers on t1.provider_id = providers.id
WHERE t1.shared_id = 2 OR t1.provider_id = 1
GROUP BY code
HAVING COUNT(code) >= 1
ORDER BY code ASC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: can you share some more code, So We are able to help you?

Comment: @AnkurTiwari  There is no more code this is a query for an index page so all I do after is return my view, currently a dd();

Comment: Please show us the full error message and show us what line it complains about.

Comment: I doubt that `from()` can use a callback as an argument.

Comment: @u_mulder as per laravel documentation it is possible https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#inserts also error would have stated that ->from() is not a function or something to that effect

Comment: __Where__ do you see that argument to `from()` is a function?

Comment: @u_mulder i'm just trying to say if it was not possible to use ->from it would have given a different error

Comment: I suppose `from` just not checks argument type.

Comment: @u_mulder could you suggest an alternative to ->from ? because of the count I am doing on the code column i need that sub query count that column so that if there are any duplicates of the code it should only show the duplicate that has a shared_id = id and provider_id = id

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667668/how-to-write-select-query-with-subquery-using-laravel-eloquent-querybuilder or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319240/laravel-how-to-use-derived-tables-subqueries-in-the-laravel-query-builder may help.

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you very much good suggestion. I have been avoiding doing it that was as i would like to keep it as one query, but wont dismiss it will give it a go, I have updated the question still getting the same error, but its at least showing the error is on the select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NigelRen's suggestion I was able to solve the problem I was having. Ideally, I would like to get the same result with a single query, but this is fine for now.

Solution was found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667668/how-to-write-select-query-with-subquery-using-laravel-eloquent-querybuilder):

```
 $subQuery = DB::table('unit_standards')->selectRaw('nqf_level,name, id, code, provider_id, shared_id, COUNT(code) as totalCodeCount, credits, type, seta_id')
            ->where('provider_id', '=', '1')
            ->whereNull('shared_id')
            ->orWhere('shared_id', '=', '2')
            ->groupBy('id','code','provider_id', 'shared_id', 'name', 'nqf_level', 'credits', 'type', 'seta_id')
            ->orderBy("code", "asc");


        $sharedUnitstandards = \DB::table(\DB::raw('('.$subQuery->toSql().') as t1'))
            ->selectRaw("t1.code, t1.id, t1.provider_id, t1.name, t1.nqf_level, t1.credits, t1.type, MAX(t1.shared_id) ,setas.name as setaName, providers.name as providerName")
            ->mergeBindings($subQuery)
            ->join('setas', 't1.seta_id', '=', 'setas.id')
            ->join('providers', 't1.provider_id', '=', 'providers.id')
            ->where('t1.shared_id', '=', 2)
            ->orWhere('t1.provider_id', '=', 1)
            ->groupBy('t1.code','t1.code','t1.id','t1.provider_id','t1.name', 't1.nqf_level', 't1.credits','t1.type','t1.shared_id', 't1.seta_id', 'setas.name', 'providers.name')
            ->havingRaw('COUNT(t1.code) >= 1')
            ->orderBy('t1.code', 'asc')
        ->paginate(50);
```